# Invalid syntax in digits-devserver?

Tags: installation, digits, nvidia-digits

After i finished Installing DIGITS

When i Running DIGITS,use

```
python digits-devserver
```

An error showed "Invalid syntax" in line6.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAb8h.png)

Answer (score 0):

`digits-devserver` is a bash script, not a Python script.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/1484#issuecomment-283416267